# Return file located in a specific path

Tags: c#, file, httpresponsemessage

I wrote a method in order to return a file using the return type `HttpResposeMessage`. I use the below code in order to attach the file.

```
file.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
  FileName = newFileName
};
file.Content.Headers.ContentType =
new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
return file;
```

How can I specify a specific path in to the filename.
I did something like this

```
fileName = "C://Templates/Order.pdf"
```

But this renames the file name as `C:_Templates_Order.pdf`

What I need is to go through the path and grab the file.

Comment: i think you are confused as to how file naming and paths work in windows, it might be time for a refresher course [Naming Files, Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a string literal by using the @ symbol in front of the quotes for your string:

```
fileName = @"C:\templates\order.pdf"
```

Or you can double escape the backslash

```
fileName = "C:\\templates\\order.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the file name using this simbol `\` instead of `/`

```
fileName = "C:\\Templates\\Order.pdf";
```